# How to store coordinates into an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, image

I am starting a new project that will involve taking two images and comparing the centers of dots inside the images. The original will be a picture with 27 rows and 15 columns of dots. The second picture will be a distorted version of the original where the dots have changed position and shape.

To begin this project I will need to store the original centers in an array.

I have made a formula to find the center of every circle in the original.

```
X: n = 0..26 [48n+5]
Y: m = 0..14 [48m+5]
```

As an example the center of dot (2,5) would be

`[48(2)+5, 48(5)+5] = [101, 245]`

TLDR: I need help storing (x,y) coorinates using the following formula

```
[X,Y] = [48(n)+5 , 48(m)+5] for n = 0..26, m = 0..14
```

**Update:**

So it looks like the 2D array is what I need to use. In the end I want to assign each coordinate a string name.

```
arr = []
for n in range(27):
    for m in range(27):
        arr.append([48*(m)+5 , 48*(n)+5])

for x in range(405):
print(arr[x])
```

Currently using this code numbers 0..404 will yield coordinate pairs `(0=[5,5] and 404=[1253,677])`. However I want an easier way to reference each coordinate pair rather than finding which object it is numerically.

I want to assign the top left dot the name A0. It will have the propertie `A0 = [5,5]` As you move right you reach the top right most dot with a center name A26. It will have the following properties `A26 = [1253,5]` Going to the bottom left dot it's center would be called O0 and have the properties of `O0 = [5,677]` and that row would span to the right until it hits the bottom right dot's center named O26 having the properties `O26 = [1253,677]`

As you can see in the diagram below I want to be able to call upon a grid of names that would be formatted in the following way.

```
A0...                          ...A26
.                                   .
.                                   .
.                                   .



.                                   .
.                                   .
.                                   .
O0...                          ...O26
```

So if I call for the coordinates of O26 it would return [1253,677]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the straight forward way for 2D array:

```
arr = []
for n in range(27):
    for m in range(15):
        arr.append([48*(n)+5 , 48*(m)+5])
```

This is the same for 3D array:

```
arr = []
for n in range(27):
    sub = []
    for m in range(15):
        sub.append([48*(n)+5 , 48*(m)+5])
    arr.append(sub)
```

For the second one you can access the value of `n` and `m` is `arr[n][m]`.

One liner for the same solution:

```
arr = [[[48*n+5 , 48*m+5] for m in range(15)] for n in range(27)]
```

**EDIT**

As you modified your question for labeling the indices, I believe the best way to do it is by a dictionary (using dict comprehention):

```
letters = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO')
dic = {letters[m]+str(list(range(27))[n]):[48*n+5 , 48*m+5] 
       for m in range(15) for n in range(27)}
```

Where:

```
>>> dic['A1']
[53, 5]
>>> dic['A26']
[1253, 5]
>>> dic['O0']
[5, 677]
>>> dic['O26']
[1253, 677]
```

Hope that helps, if it does please mark it as one, if not - let me know why.

Comment: Hey so it does look like your answer is the best one for my use case. I just updated the post to clarify some things. How would you solve the issue of labeling each of the coordinates as specified above. Also see my next comment for what I did to your 2D array to make it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I don't quite understand what your question is, but you can store your image in an array or a python list using the following code, using a nested loop:

```
centers = []

for i in range(27):
   for j in range(15): 
      centers.append((48*n+5 , 48*m+5))
```

But if you need more help with image processing and how to convert your image into a numpy array, use the following link: 
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/importing-image-data-into-numpy-arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to achieve your task

```py
[(48*(n) + 5, 48*(m) + 5) for n in range(0, 27) for m in range(0, 15)]
```

This will give you a list of tuples, with each tuple representing a coordinate point.